# using a parameter without retaining it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, retain

in this code, if `collection` is released in the class that called `init...`, what will happen to `self.title` or `self.managedObjectContext`? Don't we have to call `.itemName` on `currentCollection` rather than on `collection` itself?

```
- (id)initWithCollection:(AACollection *)collection {
    if( (self = [super initWithNibName:@"AACollectionViewController" 
                                bundle:nil]) ) {
        currentCollection = [collection retain];
        self.title = collection.itemName;
        self.managedObjectContext = collection.managedObjectContext;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: If `collection` has been released before calling this `init` method then it cannot be used at all in this method.  It's won't be release in this method so referencing either `currentCollection` or `collection` is equivalent.

Comment: I suggest you read this http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/8/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what will happen to self.title or self.managedObjectContext?

You're retaining `collection`, so nothing bad will happen. That said, it's generally a good idea to give your string properties `copy` semantics. For example, assuming `title` is a string property, if `collection.itemName` happens to give you a mutable string, you really want to make an immutable copy of it so that it won't be changed right under your nose (which could happen if you just reference the mutable string). Using `copy` will do that for you.

> Don't we have to call .itemName on currentCollection rather than on collection itself?

No. `currentCollection` and `collection` will point to the same object. It's the *object* that's retained, not the pointer. Some might consider it better style to use `currentCollection`, but it's effectively the same thing either way.

Comment: thanks Caleb, i got it now, thanks for the quick answer! for your first point with `copy`, can you explain me a bit more? do you mean that, with a mutable string, it would be possible to change the controller title from outside the controller?

Comment: @Paul If someone gives you a pointer to a mutable string, and you store that pointer, you've now got a reference to that same mutable string, and other objects (like the one that gave you the pointer in the first place) can easily modify it. What you usually want is an immutable version of that string. Specifying `copy` semantics for your property will give you exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Once you do `currentCollection = [collection retain];` both `currentCollection` and `collection` are pointing to the same object.  So, after that line, it doesn't matter which you use to access the `.itemName` property.